# Finding the total number combinations for an integer using three numbers

Tags: c, algorithm

For a given integer, *n*, I need to print all the lists of length 3 which sum to *n*. The members of the list must be non-negative integers. After printing all these lists, it must then print the number of lists that were found.

For example, if *n=2*:

- 1+0+1  = 2
- 1+1+0  = 2
- 0+1+1  = 2
- 2+0+0  = 2
- 0+0+2  = 2
- 0+2+0  = 2

Here is the program I did for lists of length 2 rather than lists of length 3:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
    int total;
    int c1=0;
    int c2=0;
    int c3=0;
    int count;

    printf("Welcome friends and mainly enemies to the thingy. Only postive intergers!!!\n That's right just enter a number here:");
    scanf ("%d",&total);
    printf ("\n\n\nWhy pick %d? Here is the list if combinations anyway,",total);

    for (count=0;count<=total;count++)
    {
        printf ("\n");
        for (c1=count;c1==count;c1--)
        {
            printf("%d ",c1);

        }
        for (c2=total-count;c2<=total-count;c2++)
        {
            printf("%d",c2);

        }

    }
    printf ("\n\nThere are %d number combinations that total %d",count,total);

}
```

The goal is to extend this from lists of length two to lists of length 3.

Additional Info: 
I can only use one other variable c3.

Comment: The question is how would I do it.

Comment: Do you mean "Given an integer *n*, print all the lists of length *m* which sum to *n*. The members of each list are all non-negative integers."

Comment: Yes, I believe that is what I mean. If by lists of lengths you mean all the combinations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
int c3 = 0;
for (int c1 = 0; c1 <= total; c1++) {       
    for (int c2 = total - c1; c2 >= 0; c2--){
        printf("%d %d %d \n", c1, c2, total - c1 - c2);
        c3++;
    }

}

printf("there are %d ways to sum to %d", c3, total);
```

Comment: That's incorrect. The *sum* of each list must be exactly 2. See the example at the end of the question. There are just 6 lists in the example. (But I must admit, I was confused about the question at first!

Comment: ... maybe just put `if(i+j+k==2) {printf ("%d %d %d", i, j, k);}` in the middle.

Comment: Even if you did you would not cover all the combinations.

Comment: Ah,  you're right.  I did misunderstand the question.  @Aaron McDaid: I'm editing the question with your addition.

Comment: @TheMegalomaniac: Actually, the code (without the if statement) prints every possible permutation of a set 3 numbers of n types. If this is not the answer you are looking for, please edit your question to state exactly what you want.

Comment: Can you explain howManyTypesofObjects and howManyObjects.

Comment: I understand that, I just need to get rid of the if statement though.

Comment: @TheMegalomaniac: edited my answer above. This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested only in the number the answer is combination with repetition of total + 1 elements 2nd class: Let me explain this: let us consider `total` number of 1s. They have 
`total + 1` gaps inbetween counting the gap before the first 1 and after the last one. You are trying to choose 3 numbers that sum up to total: we will do that by placing to separators in the gaps I just explained. The first number will be the sum of ones before the first separators, the second - the number of ones between the separators, the third - the remaining ones. Note that because we allow for the numbers to be zero we allow the separators to be placed in the same gap and also to be before the first 1 and after the last 1. This is exactly equivalent to "combination with repetition of total + 1 elements 2nd class" as I already said and is classical combinatorial problem. You can read about those kind of combinations [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition) but basically the answer will be ((total + 1) * (total + 2)) / 2. Btw I would suggest to retag this problem with at least algorithm tag.

**EDIT**: Following the request of further explanation, I will just illustrate all my thoughts with example (actually on the same example you gave in the question): we need to split 2 in three groups. 2 leads us to the number of ones we have to write: _1_1_. Here I have written the so-called-by-me gaps with '_'. Now, I will denote the two separators with '|'. Again the separators are used to determine what amount of 1s are used for the first, second and third number in the sum partition. On the left I write the combination using my notation and on the right the corresponding combination in your notation.

```
||_1_1_ -> 0, 0, 2
|_1|_1_ -> 0, 1, 1
|_1_1|_ -> 0, 2, 0
_1||_1_ -> 1, 0, 1
_1|_1|_ -> 1, 1, 0
_1_1||_ -> 2, 0, 0
```

Now, hopefully you understand better what are separators and how they are used to determine what are the three numbers used in a combination. If you increase `total` the logic stays the same, but you will need to write more if you need to illustrate the case.

Probably now you also understand why the gaps are `total + 1` and how each of the two separators can happen to be in each of these two gaps. all this leads us to the promised combination with repetition of `total + 1` elements of 2nd class.

Comment: Can you put this in simple english or can you further explain separators, gaps etc.

Comment: Okay, now that helps a bit. The part I am still completely clueless on is how I am going to put into the code.

Comment: The answer to your question is one line of code:
`printf("%d\n", ((total +1) * (total + 2)) / 2);` The fact you are not comfortable with my answer so far makes me believe i misunderstood the question?

Comment: That wasn't what I was asking, I was asking how to display all the combinations. Like for 4

Comment: For 4 it would be 004, 013, 022, etc.

Comment: @TheMegalomaniac, the word 'combinations' doesn't mean what you think it means. You should work on on explaining the actual rules more clearly. Why do you say that "004" is a combination for 4? Is it because they are non-negative integers that sum to 4? You need to make this 100% explicit in your question. I suggest you avoid the work 'combination' in your question.

Comment: @TheMegalomaniac, you can see why my confusion, just after Aaron McDaid's edits you started asking the thing you think you were. You can not do any better than just linearly iterating all the "combinations", thus the answer of Joel Cornett is the best you can do.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    unsigned int num, p1, p2, p3, count=0;

    printf("Enter a positive number : ");

    scanf("%d", &num);

    for (p1=0; p1<=num; p1++)
    {
        for (p2=0; p2<=num; p2++)
        {
            for (p3=0; p3<=num; p3++)
            {
                if (p1 + p2 + p3 == num)
                {
                    count++;
                    printf("%d + %d + %d = %d\n", p1, p2, p3, num);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\nThe total combinations for your number %d = %d", num, count);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As I see it, this is problem for mathematics not programing

In case all three integers are distinct and can be used more then once:

```
3 possibilities for 1st digit
3 possibilities for 2nd digit
3 possibilities for 3rd digit
--
27 = 3*3*3
```

Comment: It has to display all the combinations, apparently.

Comment: That's incorrect. The *sum* of each list must be exactly 2. See the example at the end of the question. There are just 6 lists in the example. (But I must admit, I was confused about the question at first!