# Finding the number of different combinations of numbers such that its total equals to sum

Tags: c, algorithm

I would like to find out the number of different combinations of non-negative numbers(can be any number, it is not fixed) such that its total equals to the sum that is provided.

for example : I have 3 numbers and i want to find the different combinations of numbers such that the sum is 4. the value of num starts from 0. no negative numbers.

For 3 numbers that sum to 4, the combinations are

```
2 0 2
2 2 0
0 2 2
0 1 3
3 1 0
0 3 1 
1 0 3
1 3 0
3 0 1
0 0 4
4 0 0
0 4 0
2 1 1
1 2 1
1 1 2
```

I saw this as an example : [Finding the total number combinations for an integer using three numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871180/finding-the-total-number-combinations-for-an-integer-using-three-numbers)

But the problem is it only uses three numbers.

Any algorithm or code will be useful. Thanks.

Comment: Any attempt at doing this yourself and letting us know of the same will be extra useful.

Comment: Infinite? 0+0+4, 1+1+2, 5+(-1)+0, 100+(-100)+4....

Comment: no negative numbers.. numbers starting from 0.

Comment: you need to show that you've attempted to solve this yourself before anyone is even going to consider helping you.

Comment: not sure how to start that why...

Comment: @lakesh: you still haven't explained what partitions you'll accept.  Below, you say that for 3 numbers and a total of 4, you get 12 ways.  Could you please list those?

Comment: The answer is still infinite.  You can add an infinite number of zeroes to any other combination that sums to the target number.  So your best option is probably a recursive solution that terminates when memory is exhausted.

Comment: Can zero be part of the combinations? Also, do you consider 1 + 2 and 2 + 1 as two different combinations of the sum 3?

Comment: zero can be part of combinations n i consider 1+2 and 2+ 1 as differnet combinations

Comment: @lakesh: what do you have against (2, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), and (1, 2, 1)?  Why aren't they valid?

Comment: What you are missing for the actual question you just added is that no result in the missing results can be 4, because each player plays at most 3 matches.

Comment: Another thing to take into consideration is that if the scoreboard was -1 -1 -1 3, no missing result can be 3 because these players lost their matches to the 4th player.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out.. was stunned after DSM's reply...

Comment: As you can see, that's a completely different problem. So if you want help with that, you can post it in a separate SO question.

Comment: sure.. i delete the last part and submit as a differnet qn... thanks once again.

Answer (score 5):

You can view this as the number of ways to put s indistinguishable  coins in n distinguishable jars. (In the example, s=4 and n=3).

As explained [here](http://2000clicks.com/mathhelp/CountingObjectsInBoxes.aspx#UnlabLab), that is C(n+s-1,s-1), which gives 15 in the example.

Answer (score 3):

If order does not matter and 0 counts too, like in example link, then

```
n=total+1
k=number-1
binomial(k+n-1,k)  #combinations whith reptetitions
or
binomial(number+total-1,number-1)
```

If you represent number 5 as

```
 1+1+1+1+1
```

and have to find number of sums sums whith 3 integers
You can see that you have to do 2 slices out of 6 calculating combinations whit repetitions.

Comment: for example, i have 3 numbers and total is 4, i can have 12 different ways of getting different numbers. but using your method, i get 12.5 after substituting the numbers in...